# How can I get URL changing in swift webview?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webview

I have this View with a WebView to turn a web page into an app.

How can I detect the url changes of the WebView, and save this url in a UserDefaults variable?

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct video: View {
    
    private let urlString: String = "https://www.google.com"
    
    var body: some View {
        // Normal WebView
        VideoWebView(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 20.0, x: 5, y: 5)
    }
}

// WebView Struct
struct VideoWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}

struct video_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        video()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to navigation changes using the below function from `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Since you're using `UIViewRepresentable`, you need to implement `makeCoordinator` function.

```
struct VideoWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: VideoWebView
        init(_ parent: VideoWebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {return}
            //do anything
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I do?  could you be more detailed with a small example please?

Comment: Hi @taxidriver , you can print the url in the last part of code (do anything) and see the result and with conditions you can do what you want.